# Adobe LiveCycle Dropdown box databinding to Text Field

Tags: adobe, livecycle

To Whom It May Concern:

I have a Dropdown list that populate a Text Field based on below code:

TextField.rawValue = Dropdownlist.rawValue

The user is Allowed Custom text Entry.

What I need is if the user adds his own text the textfield.rawValue should be empty

So far I have the follow script:

If (Dropdownlist.selectedIndex == Dropdownlist.selectedindex)
TextField.rawValue = Dropdownlist.rawValue
else
textfield.rawValue = "Empty"
endif

if I run this I get on the textField the value of "Empty" although I have selected a value that has a specific value assigned.

Your assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That is in FormCalc and I work in javascript but the issue is in the logic, not in the syntax. 
In your current setup the if statement condition will always evaluate to true - Dropdownlist.selectedIndex will always equal itself.

However, if the user has entered a custom value then the selectedIndex for that dropdown will be -1, so you can test for that.

Use this condition instead in your If statement:

```
(Dropdownlist.selectedIndex <> -1)
```